# Auto typing Issue in entry widget when taking entry 2nd time

Tags: python, tkinter

Here in my project i created 4 entry widget to take values from user after user selecting "mode" option.
When i run my code it is working properly for 1st time,if user again choose "mode" and give values in entry widget then 1st two entry widget taken values as per code but issue is arising when giving values in 3rd entry widget,and the issue is "whatever typed in 3rd widget it is automatically typed in 4th entry widget ".I am quite new to both python and Stack overflow.So if there is any mistake in way of asking ,then please guide me.
Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
from time import sleep
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.title("User Interface Monitor")
rpm=tk.IntVar()
tor=tk.IntVar()
tim=tk.IntVar()
tim1=tk.IntVar()
def  enter():
    global rpm,tor,tim,tim1
    root.rpmLabel=tk.Label(root,text="enter rpm value:")
    root.rpmLabel.grid(row=0)
    root.torLabel = tk.Label(root, text="enter Torque value:")
    root.torLabel.grid(row=1)
    root.timeLabel=tk.Label(root,text="enter  Ramp time in secs: ")
    root.timeLabel.grid(row=2)
    root.timeLabel1 = tk.Label(root, text="enter  steady time in secs:")
    root.timeLabel1.grid(row=3)
    root.e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=rpm)
    root.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    root.e1.delete(0,"end")
    root.e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tor)
    root.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    root.e2.delete(0, "end")
    root.e3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tim)
    root.e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
    root.e3.delete(0, "end")
    root.e4 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tim1)
    root.e4.grid(row=3, column=1)
    root.e4.delete(0, "end")

def gett():
    global rpm, tor, tim, tim1
    rpm = int(root.e1.get())
    tor= int(root.e2.get())
    tim = float(root.e3.get())
    tim1 = float(root.e4.get())
    print("rpm is :", rpm)
    print("Torque is :", tor)
    print("ramp time is :", tim)
    print("steady time is :", tim1)
    root.rpmLabel.destroy()
    root.e1.destroy()
    root.torLabel.destroy()
    root.e2.destroy()
    root.timeLabel.destroy()
    root.e3.destroy()
    root.timeLabel1.destroy()
    root.e4.destroy()
    t1=threading.Thread(target=getRpm,daemon=True)
    t2=threading.Thread(target=getTor,daemon=True)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
def getRpm():
    global rpm,tim,tim1,t
    st=0
    x=0
    val=int((rpm/2))
    for i in range(0,val+1,1):
        y=time.ctime()
        y=y[10:-4]
        if i==0:
            st=y
        sleep(0.001)
        x=i
    dell =time.ctime()
    dell=dell[10:-4]
    sleep(tim1)
    y=time.ctime()
    y=y[10:-4]
    print(st, x, dell, y)
def getTor():
    global tor,tim,tim1
    start=0
    b=0
    a=int(4096*(tor/100))
    for j in range(0,a+1,1):
        c=time.ctime()
        c=c[10:-4]
        if j==0:
            start=c
        sleep(0.001)
        b=j
    delta=time.ctime()
    delta=delta[10:-4]
    sleep(tim1)
    c=time.ctime()
    c=c[10:-4]
    print(start,b,delta,c)

root.Button1=tk.Button(root,text="MODE1",bg="red",command=enter)
root.Button1.pack()
root.Button1.place(x=100,y=200)
root.Button2=tk.Button(root,text="MODE2",bg="red",command=enter)
root.Button2.pack()
root.Button2.place(x=100,y=230)
root.Button3=tk.Button(root,text="Enter",command=gett)
root.Button3.pack()
root.Button3.place(x=160,y=215)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand why you use `IntVar()` - ie. `rpm=tk.IntVar()` - if you later get values directly from `Entry` - i.e `root.e1.get()` and you don't get from `IntVar()` - `rpm.get()`. Besides later you replace `IntVar()` with normal `int` - `rpm = int(...)`.

Comment: if I remove all `textvariable=...` from all `Entry` then it works correctly.

Comment: @furas,just to declare as  tk variable,then what should i take?

Comment: simply don't use `IntVar()` and `textvariable=...` - you don't need them to get value from `Entry`. And if you whan to use `IntVar()` then get value using `rpm.get()` and set value using `rpm.set(...)`. Using `rpm = ....` you assing other type of data and it is not `IntVar` any more.

Comment: Thanks @furas,it is working now after following your instruction,but a new issue arises i.e if press "mode" option twice the entry widget were not destroyed after "enter" key pressed.

Comment: you have problem because you create every elements two times but `ENTER` has access only to last elements and you see previous elements - you can't access them to delete them. You could check in `MODE` if element exist and delete them before you create again. Or rather create `Frame` with all elements only once (at start) and later show and hide this `Frame` - ie. `pack()` and `pack_forget()`. OR you should block buttons when ou show `Entry`, and unblock buttons when you press `Enter`

Comment: Again,Thank you@furas,for your valuable guidance